# Best way to iterate a subset of a 2dimensional grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, iteration

I have a 2d rectangular grid and I need to apply different functions to a subset of nodes in this grid. The subset is given by rectangular bounds e.g. row and column delimiters. Since I do not want to code the iteration with 2 for loops over and over again I am considering two approaches to solve this problem:

First create a custom iterator provider which is initialized using the rectangle limits and then keeps them while he is iterated. While this is feasible it seems quite some work to make this iterator compliant e.g. with standard stl aglorithms.

The second approach is to pass a function pointer into the function the traverses both for loops and execute it in the inner loop. This is feasible as well but might create quite ugly syntax since i have to pass member functions.

Which way is usually preferable ? And are there any clean examples for such a use case, to keep me from reinventing the wheel ?

Note: The operation is quite performance critical since the code is frequently executed

Comment: It will be helpful if you are able to describe how you choose your subsets, if they intersect in some way or totally different, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From design point of view I would say iterator approach is better, because it places less complexity on loop body (and likely there will be more complexity than in the iteration).

But I would expect better performance with functor approach. Especially if you will make it in STL-style (template parameter with expected operator() ).

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth here is the algorithm I finally implemented. The code is not complete but perhaps useful for somebody else:

```
//forward declarations
template <typename T> class Grid;
template <typename T> class rectIterator;

//friend forward declarations
template<class T>
bool operator!=(rectIterator<T> const& left, rectIterator<T> const& right);


template<class T>
class rectIterator: public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, GridTile<T> >{

public:
  typedef GridTile<T> const& const_reference;
  typedef GridTile<T>& reference;
  typedef GridTile<T> const* const_pointer;
  typedef GridTile<T>* pointer;

private:
  Grid<T>* mpGrid;
  int mRow;
  int mCol;
  int mMinRow;
  int mMinCol;
  int mMaxRow;
  int mMaxCol;


public:
  rectIterator(Grid<T>& grid,Rectangle const& rect):
    mpGrid(&grid){
    mpGrid->getRowCol(mpGrid->getTileId(rect.bottomLeft()),mMinRow,mMinCol);
    mpGrid->getRowCol(mpGrid->getTileId(rect.topRight()),mMaxRow,mMaxCol);
    mRow = mMinRow;
    mCol = mMinCol;
  }

  rectIterator():
    mpGrid(0){
    mMinRow= -1;
    mMinCol=-1;
    mMaxRow =-1;
    mMaxCol =-1;
    mCol = 0;
    mRow = 0;
  }

  rectIterator<T>& operator++(){
    if(mCol<=mMaxCol){
      ++mCol;
    }else if(mRow<=mMaxRow){
      ++mRow;
      mCol = mMinCol;
    }else{
      mCol = mpGrid->getCols();
      mRow = mpGrid->getRows();
      mpGrid=0;
    }
    return *this;
  }

  reference operator*() const throw(std::out_of_range, std::runtime_error){
    return mpGrid->at(mRow,mCol);
  }

  pointer operator->() const throw(std::out_of_range, std::runtime_error){
    return &(mpGrid->at(mRow,mCol));
  }

  int row()const{
    return mRow;
  }

  int col()const{
    return mCol;
  }

  friend bool operator!=<>(rectIterator<T> const& left, rectIterator<T> const& right);

};

template<class T>
bool operator!=  (rectIterator<T> const& left, rectIterator<T> const& right){
  return (left.mpGrid != right.mpGrid);
  //DIRTY this is no full compare but fast and sufficient at the moment
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just copying the 2d subset array to a temporary array, then passing the pointer to the start of the array to different functions?

If the same subset is passed multiple times to different functions , it should improve your cache misses and therefore improve the time spent on the subset iteration.

Comment: One Word: Performance. The Grid is quite big > 500.000 nodes and every node about 50 Byte. So the entire grid already can reach above 20 MB. Further I need to access subsets of several 1000 nodes for about 100 times and the subsets are ususaly not similar. Since this part of the program is already a major bottleneck (measured not guessed) I cannot afford the copies.